# escape character '-' in a sscanf() function

Tags: c

The problem is very simple, I have a date column in my database postgres, it returns the value as string in the format **yyyy-mm-dd**, in order to store it in my code, I need to parse the value.
The function is also very simple:

```
int parse_date(const char * s, tbDate*res)
{
    int yyyy, mm, dd;
    if (sscanf(s, "%d %d %d", &yyyy, &mm, &dd) == 3
            || sscanf(s, "%d.%d.%d", &yyyy, &mm, &dd) == 3
            || sscanf(s, "%d/%d/%d", &yyyy, &mm, &dd) == 3
            || sscanf(s, "%d-%d-%d", &yyyy, &mm, &dd) == 3)
    {
        if (mm > 0 && mm < 13 && dd>0 && dd < 32)
        {
            res->day = dd;
            res->month = mm;
            res->year = yyyy;
            return TB_PARSE_SUCCESS;
        }
    }
    return TB_PARSE_FAILURE;
}
```

The first three versions of **sscanf()** work very well, but the follow **sscanf(s, "%d-%d-%d", &yyyy, &mm, &dd)** , the format that the database  returns, are read as negative value, it means that if I pass a date  like **'2022-12-03'**, **yyyy** is correctly 2022, but **mm** and **dd**, are -12 and -3. I would avoid to put a date format function in the query of the database, and I would know if there is a way to escape the **-** charachter inside the **sscanf()**.

Comment: If the last format succeeds and the values are negative, why not just turn them back to positive again? I.e. get the absolute value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> date like '2022-12-03', yyyy is correctly 2022, but mm and dd, are -12 and -3.

That is because `"2022-12-03"` matched `sscanf(s, "%d %d %d", &yyyy, &mm, &dd) == 3` first.  Note that a `" "` in format `"%d %d %d"` match 0 or more white spaces.

Simply change order

```
if (   sscanf(s, "%d-%d-%d", &yyyy, &mm, &dd) == 3  // swapped
    || sscanf(s, "%d.%d.%d", &yyyy, &mm, &dd) == 3
    || sscanf(s, "%d/%d/%d", &yyyy, &mm, &dd) == 3
    || sscanf(s, "%d %d %d", &yyyy, &mm, &dd) == 3) // swapped
```

Comment: Damn, I Need a bit to understand this answer,  then the light, thanks you very much

Comment: @SanPei A more stringent test would be `"%4d-%2d-%2d"` (and the like for the other 3) to limit the max characters allowed per date unit.  It really comes down to do you want a wide test or and narrow one?

Comment: I think I 'm going to implement it

Answer (score 0):

It comes me in mind that the **sscanf()** function works also if is a dirty answer for example it returns 3 also if you writes '2022/09/12fooobar', so I decided to change the function and improved the check  of valid day, since I didn't find it in internet I post my own parse date function:

```
int parse_date(const char * s, tbDate*res)
{
    
    res->year=res->month=res->day=0;
    char separator;
    int acc=0;
    while (isspace(*s))
        s++;
    if(!(*s >= '0' && *s <= '9'))
        return TB_PARSE_FAILURE;
    while (*s >= '0' && *s <= '9')
        acc = (acc << 3) + (acc << 1) + *s++ - '0';///fast way to multiply for 10
    if(!*s) return TB_PARSE_FAILURE;
    separator=*s;
    s++;
    res->year=acc;
    acc=0;

    if(!(*s >= '0' && *s <= '9'))
        return TB_PARSE_FAILURE;
    while (*s >= '0' && *s <= '9')
        acc = (acc << 3) + (acc << 1) + *s++ - '0';
    res->month=acc;
    acc=0;
    if(*s!=separator)
            return TB_PARSE_FAILURE;
    s++;
   if(!(*s >= '0' && *s <= '9'))
        return TB_PARSE_FAILURE;
    while (*s >= '0' && *s <= '9')
        acc = (acc << 3) + (acc << 1) + *s++ - '0';
    res->day=acc;
    while(isspace(*s))
        s++;
    if(*s) return TB_PARSE_FAILURE;
        switch (res->month)
        {
            case 1:
            case 3:
            case 5:
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 10:
            case 12:
                if( res->day>0 && res->day<32)
                   return TB_PARSE_SUCCESS;
                else
                    return TB_PARSE_FAILURE;
            case 4:
            case 6:
            case 9:
            case 11:
               if( res->day>0 && res->day<31)
                    return TB_PARSE_SUCCESS;
                else return TB_PARSE_FAILURE;
            case 2:
               if(res->day>0 && res->day<29)
                    return TB_PARSE_SUCCESS;
                else if (res->day==29 &&(res->year%400==0 ||(res->year%4==0 && res->year%100!=0)   ) )
                    return TB_PARSE_SUCCESS;
                else
                    return TB_PARSE_FAILURE;
            default:
                return TB_PARSE_FAILURE;
            }

    return TB_PARSE_FAILURE;
}
```

It skips spaces at begin and at the end, but not inside the numbers. It checks if you use the same separator and check if the date is valid or less.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).